# Does $\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I am having trouble understanding how to apply convergence tests to complex series. Which test(s) could I use here to determine whether this series converges or diverges? Thanks!

Comment: This one has $r=|(1+2i)/\sqrt 5| =1$, and it has a bounded partial sum. However, this does not converge. Try to imitate the proof of convergence of geometric series, and use it to find a formula for partial sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\sum_n r^n$ with $r = (1+2i)/\sqrt{5}$. It is guaranteed to converge if $|r|<1$ and diverge if $|r|>1$.

Check if
$$|r| = \left|\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}\right| < 1.$$

---

I initially wanted to leave this as a hint, however I'll just go into greater detail. As discovered, you get that $|r|=1$ exactly. Hence the terms
$$\left|\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}\right|^n = 1 \not\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$, hence the series diverges by the [$n$th term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: The absolute value of $1+2i$ is $\sqrt{5}$ so this makes $|r|=1$. What does this mean?

Comment: That it does not converge, as the general term does not even go to $0$.

Comment: I also know that the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}(1)^n$ diverges, but in this series, does the fact that there is the $2i$ affect this? Specifically, I would think that $i$ when raised to different powers might cancel out some terms.

Comment: No, no such cancellations can help. For every $n$, $\lvert (e^{i t})^n\rvert = 1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. [A series whose general term does not converge to $0$ trivially diverges.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

Answer (score 3):

$z=\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}$ is a point on the unit circle, $z=e^{i\arctan 2}$. It follows that
$$ S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} z^n = z\cdot\frac{z^N-1}{z-1} $$
has a bounded modulus, but it is not converging as $N\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt 5} = \cos\varphi + i \sin \varphi \text{ where } \varphi = \arctan 2.
$$
So
$$
\left( \frac{1+2i}{\sqrt 5} \right)^n = \cos(n\varphi) + i\sin(n\varphi).
$$
The terms remain on the circle $|z|=1$ as $n$ changes. Therefore the terms do not approach $0.$ Therefore the series diverges.

(However it does have a Cesàro sum.)